# QGIS - The channel network and drainage basins are missing at the shoreline

Tags: qgis, watershed, basin

I am new to QGIS, so I hope I have included enough information.

My aim is to be able to determine, how much freshwater runs into the sea and where it enters the sea.

I start with the original DEM file, which I export and save with appropriate CRS, resolution and set no data value to -9999.
Then fill sinks (Wang & Liu) with minimum slope 0.01.
Use Strahler order to decide on which Strahler order I need.
Use Channel network and drainage basins to find the basins and channels.

As you can see from the image, the procedure works really well, except where land meets sea. It seems, that basins that share a border with the sea, are not calculated.

Any suggestions on how could I fix this?

Purple channels, grey basins, white basin borders, grayscale DEM file, white ocean

[image: Purple channels, grey basins, white basin borders, grayscale DEM file, white ocean]

QGIS version
3.30.3-'s-Hertogenbosch